# Thread pool differences between .NET Framework and .NET Core, Thread Pool starvation

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I stumbled upon an unexpected behavior when trying to pass the working code from .Net Framework 4.6.1 to .Net Core 3.1

This is a simplification of the code:

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            Console.Write($"In, ");
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient($"http://google.com");
            RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
            var response = restClient.Get(restRequest);

            Console.Write($"Out, ");
        });
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The expected output on the console is a list of "In" followed by mixed "In" & "Out" and finally some "Out" as a result of a multithreaded work. and this works as expected on .Net Framework.
Something like this:

```
In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, Out, In, Out,
In, Out, In, Out, In, Out, In, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out,
Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out,
```

But when running the exact same code on .Net Core 3.1 (same machine) it looks like we get back to write the "out" line only after all the "in" thread finished (I tested this with a lot more than 20).

```
In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In, In,
In, In, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out,
Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out, Out,
```

Meaning there is starvation on the process and if the number of added work items to the thread pool is infinite (e.g. depends on API) the HTTP response will never be handled.

I assume this happens because of the way the `ThreadPool` algorithm chooses the next thread to handle [this is a nice article on the subject](https://medium.com/criteo-labs/net-threadpool-starvation-and-how-queuing-makes-it-worse-512c8d570527)

What I don't understand is why it doesn't happen on .Net Framework, and if I can make it work somehow on .Net Core.

P.s. I'm not trying to avoid working with TPL I'm just trying to get to the bottom of this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of application did you write as example? Console, Wpf or different? UI apps have different main thread type, so it can affect results.

Comment: Does this happen also if you replace the REST call with a simple blocking call like `Thread.Sleep(500)`? I am asking in order to exclude the possibility that the discrepancy is related with the `RestClient` instead of the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: "Meaning there is starvation on the process" please explain how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: Strange that this question is being downvoted. Even if it's not about thread pool starvation, still interesting why it happens (was able to reproduce)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I tested with sleep and then it executes as excepted. However with rest client or regular httprequest - on .net core 8 (num cores) theads start executing and then 1 more thread is added by the pool up until 20, and only after that requests start completing. I cannot see why this happens in this case. There is no await so it's not about continuations being queued.

Comment: Could you try calling `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` at the start of the program, to see if makes any difference? This will configure the `ThreadPool` to create 100 threads immediately upon demand, before switching to the lazy creation algorithm.

Comment: @Hostel, the example is console app, maybe there is a difference but I'm not sure because we are only handling background threads in this case

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, as Evk said it works for thread sleep, I think that the problem lays on how the thread pool reacts to the network call back.
`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` will only delay the problem but won't solve it for infinite work item queueing

Comment: @Ian Kemp, in case I replace the for loop with `while(true)` or any other case where the calls to queue work item is infinite, the http response will never be handled

Comment: @Evk, people are strange, but why do you say this is not about thread pool starvation?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is this about. But say request natually takes about 1 second. Then I'd expect 8 threads to be started, then couple of new threads are added by the pool every second or so, and then requests should start to complete, because your request is synchronous and it already executes on thread pool thread - it doesn't need _new_ thread from a pool to complete a request. Starvation of the kind described in article happens when requset is asynchronous and it needs _new_ thread from a pool to execute continuation after async.

Comment: @NetanelSwartz your question is very interesting. Probably implementation of the `ThreadPool` changed between .NET Framework and .NET Core. I can't find any information about it.

Comment: @Evk that what I was thinking too, but then it should have work as it does on .Net Framework. The problem is that the request is not really synchronous, any time you go out to the network it will release the current thread and only on the callback it will continue from where it stopped, this continuation is done by queueing a new work item to the thread pool and that's the place where a starvation can be created and will be created any time the requests rate is faster then the response time.

Comment: "any time you go out to the network it will release the current thread" - in your case all work is synchronous, current thread (one that executes `QueueUserWorkItem`) cannot be "released" in that sense. It might be that internally it executes some asynchronous work which executes on yet another thread pool thread, then blocks waiting for it though.

Comment: I found issue on github which states that implementation of the HttpWebRequest is poor in .NET Core https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21047 - maybe this example is connected with it.

Comment: The whole *point* of using a thread pool is for the specifics of the thread creation and scheduling to be an implementation detail not considered by the consumers.  If you're writing a program that relies on some specific thread creation or scheduling mechanism then *that's a big problem* and you shouldn't be using a built in thread pool but instead using your own (assuming you can't remove the reliance on a particular implementation, which would be preferable).

Comment: Beyond the fact for new code you should use Task+await/async stuff (and in this case, you'll have 0 wait for thread pool growth and it'll even be faster than .net framework), this is indeed an issue for old sync code. Thread pool takes some (awful) time to wait to make sure new threads must be created (or not). This issue is discussed here for example: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32125#issuecomment-585358656

Comment: I quote: *"The key is it ends up requiring many more threads in order to sustain throughput. And it can take a long time for the thread pool to ramp up to the necessary level, while in the interim the system can essentially be deadlocked. That means either the app-level dev needs to explicitly set a high min thread count to force the ramp up, or we need to make the pool way more aggressive at thread injection, which harms other cases"*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[EDITED]** Here's what I found

The difference between .NET Core and .NET Framework is in the implementation of `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`. In .NET Framework, it uses `Thread.SpinWait(1)` and in .NET Core, it does `SendRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - essentially calling the async implementation and doing a Wait() on it.

Async method calls rely on [TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-5.0) to execute continuations. The TaskScheduler relies on the ThreadPool.

Normally, the thread pool starts with minThreads = # cores. Then it uses some algorithm to **slowly** increase the number of threads until it reaches maxThreads.

The code immediately posts 20 blocking jobs to the the thread pool. Continuation jobs are queued after them. The thread pool slowly increases the number of threads to accommodate the download jobs, and only then it adds a thread which processes the first Continuation job.

Another interesting twist is that if you set both min and max threads to the same low number and run the code, it deadlocks. That's because the the Continuation will never receive a thread to execute on. Some more info about the deadlock [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13611).

There are multiple ways to solve this

1. Avoid mixing sync and async code. Just go async all the way (if you can)
2. Use `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` to start with a sufficient number of threads. You need at least the number of threads as the expected number of concurrent download jobs.
3. In the sample code, if you add even a 10-50ms delay between posting the download jobs, the continuation jobs have a chance to get scheduled in between.

(the question uses something called RestClient which is probably using HttpClient or HttpWebRequest under the hood. The code below uses HttpWebRequest)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(4, 4);
    //ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            Console.Write("In, ");

            var r = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
            r.GetResponse();
            //Try this in .Net Framework and get the same result in as in .NET Core.
            //That's because in .NET Core r.GetResponse() essentially does r.GetResponseAsync().Wait()
            //r.GetResponseAsync().Wait();  

            Console.Write("Out, ");
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: But there is no `GetAsync().Wait(...)` in question, and `HttpClient` is not used either. I tried the same with `HttpWebRequest` (which does have synchronous `Get` method)

Comment: The original question uses RestClient. Not sure what it is exactly, but most probably it uses HttpClient under the hood. 
Here is the implementation of HttpWebRequest.GetResponse: return SendRequest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: Still don't know why it works different between .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect better findings and answer the difference between .NET FW and .NET CORE

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that the ThreadPool is "designed to maximize throughput, not to minimize latency".

I think that the following article gives a good starting point to understand this behavior:
[Article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170623-00/?p=96455)